# Can We Host Our React Application on GitHub? If we can do, how the way it's work?

Tags: reactjs, github, web, frameworks, host

As we can host our application on GitHub, can we also do it for React Application? The Question is, if possible how the way it's work?

I try to host it from pages option. But, it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host your React Application on Github. It is straightforward and easy.
All you need is to know how to use GitHub Pages. You can check on these [steps](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)

Comment: Yap, i found it, thanks for inform!